# CSS: display two lines as one inline tag in a text

Tags: html, css, markup

I want to design in HTML/CSS the one bureaucrate form, where fields labeled under the line. Like this one:

[image: example expectation]

I'm tried to use `inline-flex` for those fields:

HTML:

```
<p>The long text of a bureaucrate document. The commission consisting of:
<span class="labeled-field">
    <span class="field-text">
        John Doe, John Doe, John Doe, John Doe, John Doe, John Doe
    </span>
    <span class="field-label">
        (list of commission members) 
    </span>
</span>decided that the device was ready for verification and testing.
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.labeled-field {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.field-text {
    border-bottom: solid 0.05rem;
    text-align: center;
}
.field-label {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

However, `inline-flex` renders as `inline-block` and instead of word wrapping, wrapping all `.labeled-field` block:

[image]

So how to display the `.labeled-field` as `inline`, with word wrapping?

Comment: Inline elements won't split block elements in the same way they won't split a letter. You'd have to use javascript to calculate the split and reformat the html and that won't be trivial. You're likely better off with a tooltip.